# python OverflowError: 34, raised for no apparent reason

Tags: scipy, overflow, minimize

I've written a python script to evaluate a physical quantity and, for some reason, python decided to raise an `OverflowError` for no justified reason. Here's the script

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt,cos, log, pi
from scipy import integrate as sciint
from scipy import optimize as sciopt
rt=np.inf
ymin=cos(np.radians(0.5))

def func(u,y, D, rt):
    return (1.+u)**(-4)/u/sqrt(u*u-D**2*(1-y*y))
def lim_u(y, D, rt):
    return [D*sqrt(1-y*y), rt]
def lim_y(D, rt):
    return [ymin,1]
def Jfactor(D,rt,r0,rho0,tmax):
    ymin=cos(np.radians(tmax))
    Dprime=D/r0
    rtprime=rt/r0
    Msun2kpc5_GeVcm5 = 4463954.894661358
    cst = 4*pi*rho0**2*r0*Msun2kpc5_GeVcm5
    res = sciint.nquad(func, ranges=[lim_u, lim_y], args=(Dprime,rtprime),
        opts=[{'epsabs':1.e-10,'epsrel':1.e-10,'limit':1000},
        {'epsabs':1.e-10,'epsrel':1.e-10,'limit':1000}])
    return cst*res[0]

def deltaJ(rho0,J,D,rt,r0,tmax):
    #return J-Jfactor(D,rt,r0,1.,tmax)*10.**(rho0*2.)
    return long(J-Jfactor(D,rt,r0,1.,tmax)*10.**(rho0*2.))

D=104.
rt=np.inf
tmax=0.5
J = 10.**18
for j,r0 in enumerate(np.logspace(-1.,np.log10(5),10)):
    results = sciopt.minimize_scalar(deltaJ,bracket=(7.,9.),args=(J,D,rt,r0,tmax))
    print r0,results.x,results.fun
```

Very quickly: I want scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar to minimize `deltaJ` but here's (part of) the error message I get

```
  File "test2.py", line 26, in deltaJ
    return long(J-Jfactor(D,rt,r0,1.,tmax)*10.**(rho0*2.))
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Now, if `J = 10**18`, `Jfactor(D,rt,r0,1.,tmax)` is ~ 5, I expect minimize_scalar to easily scan over `rho0` to find ~ 8.5. Instead I get this error message.

As you can see, I've even bracketed the range and tried using `long()`, but nothing helped. Using instead another minimizing method, eg. bounded, gives again a weird result (function value of ~ -7e17)...
Does anybody have an idea to have this working? Thank you

Comment: I suspect the problem is `10.**(rho0*2.)`.  What is the value of `rho2` when the error occurs?  You'll get an error if `rho0*2.` exceeds 308, because the largest number that can be represented with 64 bit floating point values is about 1.8e308 (although the errror I get in that case is `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`).

Comment: for some unexplainable reason, minimize_scalar was probing higher values than I allowed it to... I solved by casting everything in log scale. thanks a lot